# CSS not syncing

Tags: html, css, eclipse, tomcat

im writing my first login form. Im using eclipse (dynamic web project) and when i'm running in on a server it's the elements are not showing properly on their specific places. but when im opening it on a normal browser everything's alright

[on java dynamic web project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mosV1.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting the question. Does the page appear differently in production than in development? Is your code compiled? Perhaps the file paths are incorrect.

Comment: Just a personal opinion but I'd refrain from using Eclipse for frontend development and use VSCode or equivalent instead, plus a dev server with hot reloading. That integrated browser in the Eclipse IDE might be making your life hard.

Comment: im on a training center and thet required to only use eclipse

Comment: Go to the **Browser** preference page and switch to an external one.

Comment: How does it look in the Internet Explorer (on Windows Eclipse uses IE by default)?